# How to remove Fake token contact signed

Tags: tokens, metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I participated in multiple airdrops and recently checked the account on etherscan which was showing multiple Coins in my wallet... I approved one of them and got some sort of "sign" pop up via metamask ... Is there any option to remove that ? or decrease the spendable limit as i fear that my other coins can also be stolen as i've signed and added a fake coin in my wallet....

Thanks ...

Answer (score 1):

Adding allowances for random tokens can't expose your other assets, unless the transactions trick you to do something you didn't intend to do. Having 'fake' tokens in your wallet doesn't hurt either, you can just forget about them there.

If you want to remove allowances, you can use something like https://revoke.cash/ or just do it manually per token.